# Teamviewer 9 not allowing me to import options from a .reg file

Tags: windows-registry, import, teamviewer

I am running a custom branded version of teamviewer 9 and have a saved .reg file of my preferences. When I go into advanced options and click 'Import' the button flashes but does not bring up a windows explorer window for me to navigate to my saved settings as it should. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

1. Exit TeamViewer.
2. Stop the service.
3. Import the .reg file, by doing double click and answer yes to the security question/s.
4. Start the service again.
5. Launch TeamViewer (Host).

Check, and it will read the settings in the registry. In my case, after doing all these steps, the <kbd>Import</kbd> button is working as expected!

Note: it is important to check if Windows is x86 or x64, as the `.reg` files exported by Teamviewer may be in the 32-bit registry format. For Windows x64, you need to change/edit (add) `\Wow6432Node` between `\SOFTWARE` and `\Version9`, i.e. `\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Version9`.

Comment: That being said, it only applies to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE.